# "%" symbol in BibTex - Latex

Tags: bibtex

I want to refer an url which contains % symbols, using BibTex.

If I just write %, the rest of the line becomes a comment.
If I write \%, then the slash also appears.

```
    @MISC{ref,
      title="title",
      note="\url{http://www.abc.com/a%20b\%20c}"
    }
```

Help? Is there any macro for "%"?

Comment: @Sergio --- the percent symbol (without the backslash) works fine for me. Please add a minimal example of your LaTeX code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you create any minimal example? The following works fine

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{ref,
      title="title",
      note="\url{http://www.abc.com/a%20b\%20c}"
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{ref}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

"%20" is a space character. You can just use `\url{http://www.abc.com/a b c` and when the user clicks the URL they will be taken to `a%20b%20c`.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, but the problem is that when inside a url, the spaces are not shown. I solved it by doing \url{http://www.abc.com/a} \url{b} \url{c}

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://www.abc.com/a\% 20b\% 20c?

Comment: still the same, it ignores the spaces and adds the slashes. Result:
http://www.abc.com/a\%20b\%20c?

Comment: This answer works for me