# biblatex and percent sign

Tags: biblatex, urls

I am trying to switch to http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis in my masters thesis, and suddenly my bibliographic references are breaking everything, despite working fine before.

A MWE is: download the template, then

First, (in main.tex) Add `Hi\cite{foo}.` below `\pagestyle{thesis}`

Second, (in example.bib) Add

```
@misc{foo,
 title = {foo},
 howpublished = {\url{foo%x}},
}
```

somewhere.

Compile/bib/compile. It will give

```
Runaway argument?
{\url {foo\field {title}{foo} \endentry \par ...
... File ended while scanning use of \field.
```

i.e. the `%` will have been replaced with `\field` etc etc etc.

How can I stop that from happening?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. The url belongs into the url field `url = {[Bibtex and percent sign](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319504)},` This can also be seen in the example bibliography

Comment: By the way, your MWE is great ;-)

Comment: You should use the `online` entry type, by the way. Details can be found in the biblatex documentation.

Comment: Thank you!! I thought I tried that though.

Comment: @Johannes_B Do you want to jot down an answer? Or do you know a good duplicate?

Comment: @moewe i looked back then for maybe five minutes, but i didn't find a good match. I don't want to write an answer for this simple matter. Ack, i just make it CW.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["%" symbol in BibTex - Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17371/symbol-in-bibtex-latex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `url` field, as is shown in the exammple bibliography and as is explained in the documentation of `biblatex`. By the way, i recommend `biber` to do the sorting instead of `BibTeX`.

If your entry is solely an internet source, use the online entry type.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @online{percent,
        author  = {many},
        title   = {Percent sign},
        url     = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%25},
        urldate = {2016-07-18},
    }
    @online{urlsInBibEntries,
        author  = {Kalle},
        title   = {Bibtex and percent sign},
        url     = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319504/},
        date    = {2016-07-15},
        urldate = {2016-07-18},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}%jobname NICHT ersetzen
\begin{document}

\cite{urlsInBibEntries}
\cite{percent}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: @moewe I also wanted to add a screenshot, but my browser doesn't want to work right now. :-/

Comment: How is it done if the *title* is  `title     = {Inequality and the 1 %},` ? Btw an existing title!

Comment: @user855443 `the 1\,\%`